# How to adjust style in Google WebFont Loader

Tags: css, webfonts

I have this code that asynchronously loads Google Fonts to avoid render blocking, I have it before ending the `</body>` of my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      WebFontConfig = {
        google: {
          families: ['Poppins:300,400,500,600,700']
        }
      };
      (function(d) {
        var wf = d.createElement('script'),
          s = d.scripts[0];
        wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js';
        wf.async = true;
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })(document);
    
    </script>
```

The problem is that the numbers have different widths? styles?
I want all the numbers to be the same in my TextArea and not look like this:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gepG.png)

PS: I am using Poppins and if I load the fonts in a common way (`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`) this error does not happen.

The code I took from [Google WebFont Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader)